# AngularJS Query Builder similar to http://redquerybuilder.appspot.com/

Tags: angularjs, query-builder, redquerybuilder

I am trying to create a complete query builder with AngularJS only. I have seen http://redquerybuilder.appspot.com/ which is awesome but not with AngularJS and I would like to create in AngularJS.

Can you please advise if it is already available or the some help because query branching would be nested.

Comment: Does it really expect the server to execute sql sent by client (browser)? Wow...

Comment: No it is not required but we need to create a similar UI so that we can make complete query with nesting conditions and pass to server to execute.

Comment: It will basically work in the Big Data environment where we need to write queries to fetch data. But think for those who knows the variables to use but don't know how to write complex nested conditions and this would be beneficial for them to send final output in XML format.

Comment: There was a blog post of somebody re-implementing RedQueryBuilder in AngularJs but I can't find it now!?  RedQueryBuilder is just JavaScript so can't you just run it on the client like any JS?

Comment: migajek - RedQueryBuilder just uses SQL as a well known and understood language for expressing a query. We use it against a Lucene "database" so not much risk of attack. On another project we used against a SQL database but only administrators could use it and even then with a really tied down SQL user.

Comment: Yes it is true as this project I am also making for specific community users who can make SQL queries in GUI mode with Angular JS...Please advise..

Comment: Any Updated on this project?  I could really use an angularJS query builder

Comment: Hi..Yes I have done with this project and I am putting this on public IP so that can share with all of you...:)

Comment: So can you post the url here? ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this is what you are looking for: http://niklr.github.io/angular-query-builder/

It is similar to the query builder of mfauveau but with additional features such as:

- Autocomplete based on selected options implemented with Bootstrap's typeahead plugin.
- Dynamic source fields based on selected source types.
- Dynamic comparison operators based on selected source field.
- Nested form validation.
- Configurable maximum for groups and conditions.
- Fancy enter and leave animations for groups and conditions.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at http://ngmodules.org/modules/angular-query-builder, this is a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

There is this: http://kindohm.com/blog/2013/09/25/knockout-query-builder.html

The guy seems to have switching blogging site so the link might stop working at some point.

Comment: The kind of UI in which Branching is always indent with its parent group is not the same as redquery builder is doing.However I have also made the same in the AngularJs and now trying to make the same UI i.e. branching part look and feel same as redquerybuilder in which you are not confusing user what is add group and condition. By next week I will be able to done the same and will publish here.

Comment: Any progress on this?

Comment: Hi. I'm working on RedQueryBuilder... is there anything that could be done to make it more acceptable to the AngularJS world?

Comment: wrap it in angularjs directive with relevant parameters. Should get a fields object and return criteria object.